# What is the Python 3 equivalent of %s in strings?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, equivalent

I've made some basic progress in python before, nothing more than command land algebra calculators to do math homework, using user-defined functions, inputs, and basic stuff. I've since taken the Python 2 course that codeacademy has, and I'm finding no equivalent of using % and %s for PY3.

I've narrowed it down to having some relation to format() , but that's as far as I could find on Google.

As a beginner, I'd really appreciate a watered down explanation to how to translate this into Python 3:

```
str1 = "Bob,"
str2 = "Marcey."
print "Hello %s hello %s" % (str1, str2)
```

EDIT: Also, I'm aware that print("Hello " + str1 + "hello " + str2) would work.

Comment: Why do you believe that they no longer work in 3.x?

Comment: % formatting continues to work in Python 3.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This didn't work in Py3: a = "Hello, "
b = "world!"
print("%s %s") % (a, b)

Comment: The reason that doesn't work has nothing to do with 3.x.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Care to elaborate? What's the equivalent of that code in PY3?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ah, a user below gave me a proper answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That was you, nevermind :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.__mod__()` continues to work in 3.x, but the new way of performing string formatting using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is described in [PEP 3101](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), and has subsequently been backported to recent versions of 2.x.

```
print("Hello %s hello %s" % (str1, str2))

print("Hello {} hello {}".format(str1, str2))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work as intended:

`str1 = "Bob,"
str2 = "Marcey."
print("Hello {0} hello {1}".format(str1, str2))`

While the use of % to format strings in Python 3 is still functional, it is recommended to use the new string.format(). It is more powerful and % will be removed from the language at some point.

Go on the Python website to see changes from Python 2.7 to Python 3 and the documentation contains everything you need.

:)

Comment: The newer versions of Python do not force writing the index inside the `{0}`. You can use `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is not related to `print`; rather, it is a string operator. Consider this valid Python 2.x code:

```
x = "%s %s" % (a, b)
print x
```

Nearly identical code works in Python 3:

```
x = "%s %s" % (a, b)
print(x)
```

Your attempt would be correctly written as

```
print("%s %s" % (a, b))
```

The `%` operator is analogous  to the C function `sprintf`, not `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

## Use f-strings in Python 3

prefix the string with `f` or `F` for variables and expressions inserted between curly braces inside the string to be evaluated inline:

```py
str1 = "John Cleese"
str2 = "Michael Palin"
age1 = 73
age2 = 78
print(f"Hello {str1}, hello {str2}, your ages add to {age1 + age2}.")
```

Note the Python3 brackets in `print()`. Apparently, string interpolation is faster than the `.format()` syntax of Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is still available in Python 3 (str.**mod**()). 
In addition to this you can make use of string formatting in Python.
e.g:

```
print("This is {}".format("sparta"))    #gives output
"This is sparta"
```

or

```
a = "Sparta"
b = "King"
print("This is {} and I am its {}".format(a,b))   #gives output
"This is Sparta and I am its King"
```